# Disable Dynamic Generated check boxes on Selection of 2 checkbox - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am generating check boxes dynamically using FormArray & Reactive Forms Module.

The thing I need here is I want to disable rest check boxes if user selects any 2 check boxes. And if he deselects any 1 the again allow him to select from others.
When 2 selection is done then all rest disable.

Below is HTML PART

```
    <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
    <label>
      <b>Time Out Period :</b>
    </label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="2" formControlName="tbl_config_TimeoutPeriod">
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="tbl_config_TimeoutPeriod.invalid && tbl_config_TimeoutPeriod.touched">
      <span style="color:red;margin-top:3px">Time Out Period field is mandatory..!</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div formArrayName="users">
      <div *ngFor="let user of users.controls; index as idx">
        <input [formControlName]="idx" type="checkbox"   >
        <button (click)="deleteUserField(idx)">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!userForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="addUserField()">Add More User</button>
  </form>
```

Below is TS PART

```
  userForm = new FormGroup({
        tbl_config_TimeoutPeriod: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        users: new FormArray([
          new FormControl('', Validators.required)
        ])
      });

 get users(): FormArray { return this.userForm.get('users') as FormArray; }
  get tbl_config_TimeoutPeriod() { return this.userForm.get('tbl_config_TimeoutPeriod'); }

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log(this.userForm.value); // Gives Complete form data
  }

  addUserField() {
      this.users.push(new FormControl(''));
  }

  deleteUserField(index: number) {
    this.users.removeAt(index);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your input like so:

```
    <input type="checkbox" 
        [disabled]="amountChecked==2&&!input.checked
            ?'disabled'
            :''" 
        (change)="handleCheck($event.target)" 
        #input>
```

...and add this to your component.ts:

```
amountChecked=0
handleCheck(ev){
  if(ev.target.checked==true){
    this.amountChecked++
  }else{
    this.amountChecked--
  }
}
```

also, change the **deleteUserField()** method:

```
deleteUserField(index: number,el:HTMLInputElement) {
  el.checked=false
  this.handleCheck(el)
  this.users.removeAt(index);
}
```

[See proof of concept](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5x4wy)

- **amountChecked** gets altered on any change on the checkbox value. It holds the value for how many checkboxes are checked.
- **[disabled]** binds to a custom amount that you set (2 here), where if this value is reached, all non-checked checkboxes get disabled.
- **#input** is a template reference variable, scoped to every single ngFor-loop, so always referencing the input itself. This is to avoid disabling the checked checkboxes.

### Edit

As requested, I updated the link to the example, mergin all code from the question with my solution. additionally, I made some changes above and in the example for being able to delete inputs and handling state correctly.

Comment: Bro I can see it works in your proof of concept but when i am implementing in my code it is not working. Can u create a stackblitz for the same that would be really very helpfull..

Comment: i copied your code in a new project with my additions [here](https://angular-x5x4wy.stackblitz.io)

Comment: oops, sorry, wrong link, anyway, there was still a problem, so [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5x4wy) is the working example. Before it wasn't handling the deletion of checkboxes. I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks Brother Works fine now only one last thing, when i submit the form the users array of checkbox values are coming null

Comment: Hello Buddy you there ? Need some help

Comment: hey, sorry, missed your comment. I think i missed the **[formControlName]="idx"** part. I'm not too familiar with reactive forms, but putting it in seems to do it

Comment: OK brother i will check that out

Comment: But by using this [formControlName]="idx" it breaks our logic restricting 2 two checkboxes

Comment: Buddy you there its urgent ?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I'm at work, so I can't response usually. Anyway, look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3zdppr). that should re-enable the max-checked-logic. basically you cant use **[disabled]** binding, but have to use **control.disable() or control.enable()** If all is as you wish, I will update the answer in a few hours

Comment: No :) I meant check the solution in the link in my last comment, if it is what fulfills all needs i update. I think it should be good to go, but just to be sure you check it

Comment: Ok I checked but there are some errors popping in the console.

Comment: ok, please check again, errors were due to a **{{users|json}}** on top that i had in it for checking results. also, attribute binding to **disabled** wasnt gone. please check.

Comment: Sure brother i will just check